# Dump to Storage Container failed ingestion in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I've problems when I ingest data from an IoT Hub in my Azure Data Explorer.

When I execute on ADX the command to see the errors:

```
.show ingestion failures | where FailedOn >= make_datetime('2021-09-09 12:00:00')
```

I get the error message:

```
BadRequest_NoRecordsOrWrongFormat: The input stream produced 0 bytes. This usually means that the input JSON stream was ill formed.
```

There is a column with **IngestionSourcePath**, but it seems to be an internal URI of the product itself.

I read in another Stack Overflow question, that there is a command in ADX to dump the failed ingestion blob into a container with this syntax:

```
.dup-next-failed-ingest into TableName to h@'Path to Azure blob container'
```

The problem is that this command is not documented through Microsoft documentation.

The questions are:

- What are the full syntax of this command?
- Can you show me some examples?
- Which are the needed permissions to run this command over ADX and also over the Blob Container?
- Is another command to remove this dump after fix the ingestion errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full syntax of the command is:

.dup-next-failed-ingest into TableName to h@'[Path to Azure blob container];account-key'

or

.dup-next-failed-ingest into TableName to h@'[Path to Azure blob container]?SAS-key'

We will add the documentation for this command.

The error you encountered most likely indicates that the JSON flavor you are using does not match the flavor you specified for the data connection, or that the JSON objects are not syntactically solid. My recommendation would be to make sure you use the "MultiJSON" as the data connection format for any JSON payloads.

When looking at the interim blobs created using this command, please keep in mind that you will not be looking at the original events sent into the IoT Hub, but batches of these events, created by ADX internal batching mechanism.